# React route to an external link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to route the user to an external website when they visit this path /help without breaking the back button so they can come back to my app if they click back.

```
<Route path="/help" component={()=>{
window.location.href="https://example.com";
return null;
}}/>
```

if the user visit /help they get redirected to https://example.com. if they click back, they go back to /help which redirects them again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the good old anchor tags.

React-router is a routing system for a Single-Page Application. That all the routes should be defined in your page and be encapsulated within your app.

For external links, it's okay to use `anchor` tags.

```
<a href="www.example.com/help" />
```

The rule of thumb here would be :-

1. If the link is within your app, use `React-Router`.
2. If not, use `anchor` tags